# How to match all php variables inside double quotes

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace `$bar` inside:

```
"foo$bar baz"
```

and also `$foo` and `$bar` inside:

```
"xxx $foo xxx $bar"
```

by some value. So far I have regex that match all variables that much php variable but not inside single quote that is not object and method invocation:

```
%'[^']+'(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!\\\\)\\$([\w./]+)\b(?!->)%
```

and I replace the values using json_encode but if the value is inside double quote I don't want to use json_encode so the value for `"$foo"` will not be `""something""`.

I've try this code:

```
while(preg_match('%("(?:[^"]|\\\\")+?)\\$([\w./]+)\b(?!->)%', $str)) {
    $str = preg_replace_callback('%("(?:[^"]|\\\\")+?)\\$([\w./]+)\b(?!->)%', function($matches) use ($context, $self) {
        return $matches[1] . $self->get_context_var($context, $matches[2]);
    }, $str);
}
```

but it don't work when there is this string:

```
"/$username|$username/" && $username != ""
```

it replace 3rd `$username` it should not match that one.

Comment: `eval('$result = "xxx $foo xxx $bar";');`

Comment: This regex you have will stumble at the escape sequences, when there is a literal backslash before the literal `$`. A regex solution will not be 100% safe here.

Comment: Is the code snippet always going to be that simple? Or can it be arbitrarily complex (e.g. entire scripts)? If it's abitrarily complex, you can't do that. You can NOT write a single regex, no matter how powerful, that can implement a complete PHP code parser.

Comment: @MarcB I don't want complete parser I only need this one simple case, php variable inside double quotes.

Comment: then why can't you use a simple string replacement? `str_replace($your_string, '$foo', 'whatever foo should be')`?

Comment: @MarcB Becase I have specal cases like: inside double quoted string that should be not json_encode single quote that should not be replaced and without quotes should be json_encode also it should be not replaced if it's object and method invocation.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I can't use eval I need to get the variables from handlebars context.

Comment: Why not `str_replace('""', '"', $doubleQuotedString);` ?

Comment: @revo what about if it's empty string?

Comment: You said *I need to replace `$bar` (inside double quotes)* and then said *I don't want to use `json_encode` (inside double quotes)*. Doesn't it simply mean you don't need to catch variables inside double quotes at all?

Comment: @revo I'm replacing all php variable by json_encode and before that I want to replace all php variables if they are in double quotes without using json_encode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Update***

It can be done in one step, while replacing all normal `$var`s, you capture double quoted strings and replace `$var`s inside them with a different thing (escaped characters inside double quoted strings is considered):

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/sOrAu)

```
preg_replace_callback('~\'[^\']+\'(*SKIP)(*F)|"(?<double>[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*)"|(?<!\\\\)\$([\w.\/]+)\b(?!->)~', function($match) {
    if (!empty($match['double'])) {
        return '"'.preg_replace('/(?<!\\\\)\$([\w.\/]+)\b(?!->)/', 'NOT_JSON_ENOCDE', $match['double']).'"';
    } else {
        return "JSON_ENOCDE";
    }
}, $str);
```

Comment: what about if double quote is escaped like `"foo\"$bar"`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. PS: It's still two steps for double quoted strings.

Comment: No this is not two steps, `preg_replace()` is mandatory and you should see by your answer you will have three `preg_replace_callback` calls in your code which is unnecessary. Also the regex you used doesn't capture right parts if there is an escaped character - [**check here**](https://regex101.com/r/tY5vM2/1).

Comment: Your solution almost work, it fail on empty string, I've fixed that using this regex `'~\'[^\']+\'(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<double>"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*")|(?<!\\\\)\$(?<name>[\w.\/]+)\b(?!->)~'` and removing quotes around  preg_replace

Comment: regex that match odd number of escape quote inside string as part of the string `$re = '~\'[^\']+\'(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<double>(?<!\\\\)"(?:(?:(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*\\\\)"|[^"])*(?<![^\\\\]\\\\)")|(?<!\\\\)\$(?<name>[\w.\/]+)\b(?!->)~';`